# Class pointer field with variable(somewhat) type?

Tags: c++

I have a template structure called "bitmap", looks like this:

```
enum PixelOption { I8, I16, I32, I64, F32, F64 };

template <PixelOption T> struct PixelOptionType;
template<> struct PixelOptionType < I8 > { using type = uint8_t; };
template<> struct PixelOptionType < I16 > { using type = uint16_t; };
template<> struct PixelOptionType < I32 > { using type = uint32_t; };
template<> struct PixelOptionType < I64 > { using type = uint64_t; };
template<> struct PixelOptionType < F32 > { using type = float; };
template<> struct PixelOptionType < F64 > { using type = double; };

template <PixelOption T>
struct Bitmap {
    using type = typename PixelOptionType<T>::type;

    uint32_t Width, Height;
    type* pData;

    Bitmap(uint32_t Width, uint32_t Height, uint32_t X, uint32_t Y, uint32_t SourceWidth, void* pData) {
        this->Width = Width; this->Height = Height; 
        this->pData = &reinterpret_cast<type*>(pData)[SourceWidth * Y + X];
    }

    type* Pixel(const uint32_t &X, const uint32_t &Y) {
        return &pData[Width * Y + X];
    }
};
```

Now I want to include a vector of those bitmap pointers in a struct called "channel", sorta like

```
struct Channel {
    std::vector<Bitmap*> Fragments;
}
```

But the compiler wants me to declare template parameters for the pointers. All the bitmaps in a channel will be the same type anyways (hence channel) but adding a template parameter to the channel struct would really serve no other purpose than pushing the problem forward since I'm planning to include a vector of channels in the upcoming "layer" struct and would be facing the same issue.

I wanted to include the pixel option in the constructor parameters of the channel struct but cant seem to find my way past that vector declaration without runtime casting (which I'm hoping to avoid).

I tried creating a struct "BitmapBase" with dummy functions and inheriting it in the bitmap but by creating a bitmapbase vector, storing bitmap objects in it and calling pixel I only got the dummy function result, not (as i had hoped) the replacing real function result.

Does anybody have an idea how to deal with this?

Comment: making the pixel virtual did the trick! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go the `BitmapBase` route, you need to make `BitmapBase::Pixel` `virtual`. Also, if the issue is just about inconvenience of `std::vector<Bitmap<T>*>`, you could use [template aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias). For example:

```
using <template T> BitmapPtrVec = std::vector<Bitmap<T>*>
```

Comment: note: I ended up pushing the problem forward anyways since bitmaps had different return types and using bitmapbase it would return the virtual dummy function type but all the channel return types will be the same so i can use it there no problem.